# MonoTouch.Dialog UITableView without margins

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

How can I create `UITableView` with MonoTouch.Dialog which has no margins?

At the moment once you create new Section it will add margins around the table and makes elements rounded. I want the look of simple `UITableView` which has no margins (top, left, bottom etc.), is this achievable anyhow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you want is to create your `DialogViewController` with the `UITableViewStyle.Plain` style. E.g.

```
var root = new RootElement ();
var d = new DialogViewController (UITableViewStyle.Plain, root);
```

The default style value is `UITableViewStyle.Grouped` and gives each element a rounded-rect look.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for! :) Sorry can't up vote as I don't have enough points yet.

Comment: I kept trying to find how to accomplish this by figuring out a way to make a subclass of `Section` or `Element` that would force its way to be full width. Glad to be pointed in the right direction. Searches for "full width MonoTouch.Dialog Section" are not helpful for a reason, I guess.